# Error when passing file content to Celery task: "Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable"

Tags: django, pandas, rest, asynchronous

**Description:**
I'm encountering an error when trying to pass file content directly to a Celery task in a Django application. The error message I'm getting is:
`"Error: Object of type InMemoryUploadedFile is not JSON serializable"`
**API View:**

```
class TradeMappingView(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = InputSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        file_content = serializer.validated_data['file']
        column_mapping = serializer.validated_data["column_mapping"]
        merge_columns = serializer.validated_data.get("merge_columns", {})
        values_to_replace = serializer.validated_data.get("values_to_replace", {})

        try:
            synchronizer.delay(
                file=file_content,
                file_type="trade",
                columns_to_rename=column_mapping,
                merge_columns=merge_columns,
                values_to_replace=values_to_replace,
            )

            return Response("Trades synchronization started successfully.", status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response(f"Error: {e}", status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

**Celery Task:**

```
@shared_task
def synchronizer(file, file_type, columns_to_rename=None, values_to_replace=None, merge_columns=None):
    try:
        synchronizer_instance = Synchronizer(
            file=file,
            file_type=file_type,
            columns_to_rename=columns_to_rename,
            values_to_replace=values_to_replace,
            multiple_sheets=None,
            merge_columns=merge_columns
        )
        synchronizer_instance.run()
    except Exception as e:
        raise synchronizer.retry(exc=e)
```

I've noticed that the error occurs even though the data passed to the Celery task passes the validation of the InputSerializer. How can I resolve this error and successfully pass the file content to the Celery task?